# Using mysqli_insert_id to insert last ID from one table into another

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-insert-id

I'm trying to use `mysqli_insert_id()` to get the last id value from one table and insert it into another table. The following code gets me a value of 0 for the ID (but the timestamp is correct). Any ideas? I think there are a few ways to do this but I can't seem to make it work.

```
<?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("hostname","dbname","password","db");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$sql = "INSERT INTO `thelineexchange`.`lines` (`id` ,`line` ,`author` ,`email` ,`time`)
VALUES (NULL, '".$_POST['input-poem-text']."', '".$_POST['input-author']."',       '".$_POST['input-email']."',NOW( ));";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }

$id = mysqli_insert_id($con);

$sqlmsg = "INSERT INTO `linesid` (`id`, `time`) VALUES ('".$id."', NOW())";
mysqli_query($sqlmsg);
;

$url = 'yourline.php';
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';  


 ?>
```

Comment: You're really asking for SQL injection here, but are you certain your first insert works?

Comment: Does your `lines` table have an auto-increment column?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you already have the ID and timestamp stored in the first table, why would you want to store the exact same information again in another table?

Comment: @EternalHour, yes the first insert definitely works. The timestamp also works.

Comment: @MikeW yes, lines uses auto-increment.

Comment: @jeroen, I need to somehow flag that certain IDs are unavailable while someone is 'using' them (called by different PHP on the next page). The idea is that a user inserts a line into the database, which is then flagged as available by its ID in the second table; when another user receives a line from the next page, it will be temporarily removed from the second table while they decide if they want that line or not. I need to make sure that no two users at once are receiving the same line at once. That probably makes no sense.